# Slicing nested list. Explanation

Tags: python, list

```
x = [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]
print(x[1][1][1])
```

Could you explain it to me, why the result is `4`.

Comment: if you understand how basic indexing works, i.e `x[1]` then just decompose it piece by piece slowly adding each index and observing each intermediate result

Comment: Python indices are zero-based

Comment: @dexter7d, you may accept the answer that helped you understanding it and delete your comment-based answer, cheers!

Comment: I have deleted that pseudo answer of mine :) I am happy to accept the best answer but how? Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: @dexter7d voting is different than accepting an answer, you can always accept the answer by click on the tick mark beneath the voting arrow. cheers

Comment: I get it now. Ive ticked off the answers I find the best.

Comment: you can only tick one as an answer. You can upvote multiple though.

Comment: @dexter7d you cannot accept multiple answers, but the one that helped you solve your problem better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]

x[1] = [2,[3,4],5]

x[1][1] = [3,4]

x[1][1][1] = 4
```

Remember you start indexing from 0. So `x[0] = 1` and `x[1] = the entire nested list`

Also remember that a nested list is detected as a single entity. In this case,
`x` contains 3 elements which are `1`,`[2,[3,4],5]` and `6`. The second element now has an index position of `1` and also contains 3 elements which are `2`,`[3,4]` and `5`. Same for the nested loop `[3,4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since indices is `0` based.

```
x = [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]

# The element placed on 1 of [1,[2,[3,4],5],6] i.e. [2, [3, 4], 5]
print(x[1])  

# The element placed on 1 of [2, [3, 4], 5] i.e.  [3, 4]
print(x[1][1]) 

# The element placed on 1 of [3, 4] i.e. 4
print(x[1][1][1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, [3, 4], 5]
[3, 4]
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]`

What `x[1][1][1]` does is:

Takes the second element:

`[2,[3,4],5]`

second element from that list:

`[3,4]`

second element

`4`

So it makes perfect sense.

It's the second not first element because lists in python are numerated from 0.

Comment: So we simply take the 1st element from the list and then that first element becomes a new list and so on ? Is that right?

Comment: it's the second element, 
you take this second element - you got another list from which you take second element which is also a list from which you take second element which is a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]
```

is actually like below when you look at it as index based:

```
InnerList-2 Index->       0 1
InnerList-1 Index->    0 1     2
OuterList Index->   0 1           2
x =                [1,[2,[3,4],5],6]
```

So, this translates to:

```
x[1] ->    [2,[3,4],5]
x[1][1] -> [3,4]
x[1][1] -> 4
```